# Cannot get UIAlert to work

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, button, uialertview, exc-bad-access

Does somebody see something wrong with this? I have an UIAltertView but get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I click any of the two buttons:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"First Sync"];
    [alert setMessage:@"The App is going to do its first synchronisation. This might take a few moment..."];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

and to catch the response:

```
#pragma mark UIAlertView
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != 0)
    {
            NSLog(@"TEST1");
        return;
    }   
NSLog(@"TEST2");
}
```

It must be something simple...

Comment: What happens when you show the alert? Is there any chance that alert's delegate gets deallocated? (try running with NSZombiesEnabled)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The Alert is created in a Thread which finishes before the response, so I have to find a way to have the thread wait for the response, but that is a bit difficult while keeping the code clear as the Alert cannot be on the thread paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted above, the problem was that the UIAlert was generated in a thread. By using an NSCondition and firing the Alert into a background thread I got the worker thread to wait while the background thread waits for a response from the user. Once the response comes it signals the worker thread to continue (as the required data is stored in the database at that point).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the designated initializer:

`initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`